# How to pass parameter to cmd.exe and get the result back into C# Windows application

Tags: c#

GUI of my program.
[image]

I want to pass parameter as **dir** to **cmd.exe** with `.NET` `Process` class and get correct output into the c# program.

Source:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace MyCmd
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            comboBox1.Items.Add("cmd.exe");
            comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
        }

        private Thread t;

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            object[] param = new object[] { comboBox1.Text, txtParams.Text };
            if (param.Length > 0 && comboBox1.Text != "")
            {
                t = new Thread(() => doTask(param));
                t.IsBackground = true;
                t.Start();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Invalid parameters!");
            }
        }

        private void doTask(object[] param)
        {
            Process proc = new Process
            {
                StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
                {
                    FileName = param[0].ToString(),
                    Arguments = param[1].ToString(),
                    UseShellExecute = false,
                    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                    CreateNoWindow = true
                }
            };
            proc.Start();
            while (!proc.StandardOutput.EndOfStream)
            {
                string line = proc.StandardOutput.ReadLine();
                this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
                {
                    txtResponse.Text += line + Environment.NewLine;
                });
            }
            proc.WaitForExit();
        }
    }
}
```

**This is output**
[image]

I want to launch **cmd.exe** and then enter **dir** then, it **list the directory info into my application**.

**UPDATED:**

Source updated:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace MyCmdV2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            comboBox1.Items.Add("cmd.exe");
            comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
            proc = new Process();

            proc.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                FileName = "cmd.exe",
                UseShellExecute = false,
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                RedirectStandardInput = true,
                CreateNoWindow = true
            };
            proc.Start();
        }

        private Process proc;

        private Thread t;

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            t = new Thread(() => doIt());
            t.IsBackground = true;
            t.Start();
        }

        private void doIt()
        {
            if (txtParams.Text.ToLower() == "cls")
            {
                txtResponse.Text = "";
            }
            else
            {
                proc.StandardInput.WriteLine(@txtParams.Text);
                while (!proc.StandardOutput.EndOfStream)
                {
                    string line = proc.StandardOutput.ReadLine();
                    this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
                    {
                        txtResponse.Text += line + Environment.NewLine;
                    });
                }
                proc.WaitForExit();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is an example query only.I need to **run any exe program** with **parameters**.
List all my program in to `ComboBox` and then pass the parameters in `TextBox`.

Some time i need to pass parameter as **IP** address like this. `\\192.168.1.2`

```
Ex: psinfo.exe \\192.168.1.2
```

But C# it's store as `\\\\192.168.1.2`. How to remove that escape sequence characters in parameter.

Comment: have you debugged to see if the argument is filled in startinfo?

Comment: I have created a class library for exactly this purpose: https://github.com/lassevk/commander - It does not have a nuget package yet, haven't gotten that far, and I don't consider it production ready as I am not sure I have tested everything, but you might want to at least look at the code there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code looks fine as it did pass "dir" as an argument. Your code did the same as executing "cmd.exe dir". Are you wanting to launch cmd.exe and then enter dir so it lists the directory structure? If so, you'll need to redirect the standard input like you did the standard output and then write dir to the input stream.

**UPDATE**

Code to execute your command:

```
    private void doTask(object[] param)
    {
        Process proc = new Process
        {
            StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                FileName = param[0].ToString(),
                //remove this line, it's not needed
                //Arguments = param[1].ToString(),
                UseShellExecute = false,
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                //Add this line so you can write commands
                RedirectStandardInput = true,
                CreateNoWindow = true
            }
        };
        proc.Start();

        //now write your command with WriteLine so it mimics an enter press
        proc.StandardInput.WriteLine(param[1].ToString());

        while (!proc.StandardOutput.EndOfStream)
        {
            string line = proc.StandardOutput.ReadLine();
            this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
            {
                txtResponse.Text += line + Environment.NewLine;
            });
        }
        proc.WaitForExit();
    }
```

Comment: Yes I want to launch cmd.exe and then enter dir so it lists the directory info into my application.

Comment: @Jimmer Updated my answer to show how to execute the dir command. Tested this locally and it worked fine.

Comment: How to go to back directory ex: `cmd.exe` then `cd..`

Comment: Any commands you would type in the actual cmd.exe window you would just write to the StandardInput. So `proc.StandardInput.WriteLine("cd ..");` then `proc.StandardInput.WriteLine("dir");`

Answer (score 1):

Seems that standard input and output are already correctly set. If you take a look in the manual [here](http://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html), you should get a better picture of what to do. I performed two tests using the Windows run feature. The first one was `cmd dir`, the same as yours and it failed miserably. The second one was `cmd /K dir`, which produced what I think is the intended output. The used switch leaves the cmd window open, check the manual for other switches that close the process after the command is done.

One more thing to note, while most of the things run in the cmd are programs, commands like "dir" and "cd" are just that, commands, and you won't find `dir.exe` or `cd.exe` anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

When you invoke cmd.exe, you need to use the `/c` parameter. Go to your command prompt and type this:

`cmd.exe dir`

This is essentially what you do in your application, which gives to the same output as in your application.
Now try:

`cmd.exe /c dir`

This is the output you are looking for. So, you tell cmd.exe to run the command `dir` by using the `/c` param.

So, your `ProcessStartInfo.Arguments` would look like this:

```
private void doTask(object[] param)
        {
            Process proc = new Process
            {
                StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
                {
                    FileName = param[0].ToString(),
                    Arguments = "/c " + param[1].ToString(),
                    UseShellExecute = false,
                    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                    CreateNoWindow = true
                }
            };
            proc.Start();
```

I have recreated your solution, and this works as expected.